# tcpdump read both ipv4 and ipv6 packets from pcap

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6, wireshark, tcpdump

I'm trying to gain some info from payload of TCP and UDP. The filter

```
(tcp.stream && tcp.flags.push == 1) || udp.stream
```

in *Wireshark* gives me both IPv4 and IPv6 packets.

But I can't figure out how to do that through the *tcpdump*. I tried:

```
tcpdump -X 'tcp[tcpflags] & tcp-push != 0 or udp' -r some.pcap
```

But there are only IPv4 packets. Something like

```
tcpdump -X '((tcp[tcpflags] & tcp-push != 0) or udp) and (ip or ip6)' -r some.pcap
```

also displays only IPv4 packets. Any examples would be helpful.

Comment: I think that is a bug in `tcpdump`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it will help you:

```
tcpdump 'ip6[6]==17 or udp or (ip6[6]==6 and ip6[53]&8!=0) or tcp[13]&8!=0' -X -r some.pcap
```

In *tcpdump* you can't retrieve ipv6 packets the way you are trying, because it [does not support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47878459/problems-sniffing-ipv6-syn-ack-packets) (at least up to 4.9.2 version) BPF filters under ipv6.

So,

- `ip6[6]==17` means ***udp over ipv6*** (the 6th byte is the ipv6-header protocol field), `ip6[6]==6` means ***tcp over ipv6*** respectively;
- `ip6[53]&8!=0` means ***tcp-push over ipv6*** (40 bytes of ipv6-header and 13th byte of tcp-header, which is tcp-flags);
- `tcp[13]&8!=0` is the same as your `tcp[tcpflags] & tcp-push != 0`.

More info: [ipv6 tcpip pocketguide](https://www.sans.org/security-resources/ipv6_tcpip_pocketguide.pdf) and [here](https://www.packetlevel.ch/html/tcpdumpf.html).

Keep in mind (!): ***Using `ip6[6]` to identify the protocol fails if any extension headers are present*** (as pointed by [kasperd](https://superuser.com/users/326546/kasperd)). More about ipv6 extension headers [here](https://www.cisco.com/en/US/technologies/tk648/tk872/technologies_white_paper0900aecd8054d37d.html). Hence such way tcp-packets over *ipv6 with extension headers* will not be captured.

Also, you can write your own simple filter for specific (e.g. to get the last character of payload) purposes like:

```
perl -le 'print map { /(?:Flags \[P\.\]|UDP).*(\S)$/s } split /\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{6}/, `tcpdump -X -r some.pcap 2>/dev/null`'
```

Comment: Using `ip6[6]` to identify the protocol fails if any extension headers are present. `ip6[53]&8!=0` can still match packets that aren't TCP.

Comment: @kasperd Thanks, fixed. About extensions: it wasn't stated that this way is versatile, however, it can be useful. So you are welcome to give a more versatile usage examples of `tcpdump` with ipv6. I'll be happy to use it :)